# XMLHttpRequest returning response in inspector but null when accessing it

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I have the following function:

```
var submit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = '*removed*';
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password }));
    console.log(xhr); 
}
```

Everything works just fine, I get the response I expected. This is the response (short):

```
readyState: 4

response: {token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkI…DQxfQ.s4Py_lmVK1-Ji9F573ZFddtpdnb2qa1ETHHluG11l44"}

responseType: "json"

status: 200

statusText: "OK"
```

I need to grab the token contained in the "response" field for future requests. The problem is that, if I call xhr.response it says "null". No matter how I call any single element of the object returned, I can't access them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm running this from localhost, and trying to access herokuapp.com API. I'm not getting error messages in the console.

Comment: Nothing in code you've provided examines `xhr.response`. Try providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I used XMLHttpRequest, I remember it having an `onreadystatechange` event that is triggered once the asynchronous call is complete, that you have to write a handler for, in order to access the response from the http call.

Further reading from the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)

```js
submit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = '*removed*';
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = "json";
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
  }
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password }));
}
```

Comment: Ok you just literally saved my day, this worked for me. Genius!! Thanks a lot! :)